# True definition of TV viewership?

Tags: audience-measurement

When you say TV viewership of 300 million, is it actually the number of people watching it(300 million in our case) or the number of TVs it is being displayed on(300 TVs)? Because often more than one people might be watching a specific program on one particular TV. Can someone clarify it?

Comment: Collectively, the viewers of a television program or other video broadcast? according to dictionaries (MW / Cambridge /  Collins) and Wikipedia. You have many many explanations just on WP, with many links. What's unclear to you then?

Comment: Typically, I believe it is difficult (at least with broadcast TV) to track who is watching what. Nielsen households are, or at least were, a sample of households which record what they view which is then used to judge how many households watched a show (eg 30% of Nielsen households watched this show, ergo we can say 30% of people watched this show). It is obviously a lot more complicated than that, with relation to demographics etc. The Nielsen households would also indicate how many people watched in that household. I imagine this has changed a lot for streaming services.